# How do I tell React that a variable will be available globally after deploying an app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, global, production

I have a React app that is going to be deployed to a service (Overwolf) that uses it's own global variable and methods. Of course, that variable becomes available only after i've built my application and launched it in Overwolf's environment.
But React is refusing to build, cuz `'overwolf' is not defined`.

How do i overcome this and make an application build successfully?

Comment: can you include your code for the service and app and how you are deploying it

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using typescript - if so, add https://github.com/overwolf/pubg-dev-challenge-samples/blob/master/ow-typescript-sample/typings/overwolf.d.ts to your typings

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem before.
And then I use 'window.xxx=' to solve such problem. And use window.xxx to call it.